# Can all of them be different?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

**Edit:** Cross-posted to MathOverflow [**here**](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171836/can-all-of-them-be-different) (and resolved).

---

Let $G=\{g_1,g_2,...,g_n\}$ be a group with $e=g_1$ and $n$ is odd,

Set $$a_1=g_1$$
$$a_2=g_1g_2$$
$$a_3=g_1g_2g_3$$
$$a_n=g_1g_2...g_n$$

I am looking for example that all $a_i$ are different from each other i.e. $G=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$. By the way it is  clear that $a_i\neq a_{i+1}$.

Comment: Are you looking for an example that holds for all $n$ or just a particular value of $n$? For $n = 1,2$, the cyclic group works.

Comment: It doesn't seem like any cyclic group works ($\Bbb Z/(3)$, $\Bbb Z/(5)$, and $\Bbb Z/(6)$ all seem to be counterexamples unless I'm misunderstanding), but if $G = \Bbb Z/(4)$ and $g_i = i - 1$, you have $a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 1$, $a_3 = 3$, $a_4 = 2$.

Comment: sorry for not to write, $|G|$ is odd.

Comment: In that case, no abelian group can work, since then $a_n=1$.

Comment: @Nishant: you are right.

Comment: @Nishant: that's not correct (as the cyclic group of order $2$ shows). In a finite abelian group, the product of all elements is the same as the product of all elements that are their own inverses (elements of order $2$); however, this can definitely fail to be the identity (for example, any cyclic group of even order).

Comment: @GregMartin: we assumed that $|G|$ is odd, check previous comments.

Comment: Troll answer, $G=\{e\}$.

Comment: @mesel: I have added a CW answer to this question which is the action that has been suggested on meta for questions which have answers on MO; see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9210/what-to-do-with-questions-that-are-exact-duplicates-from-mathoverflow/9214#9214) for example.

Answer (score 2):

This question was cross-posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/171836/21564) where it was answered by Joni Teräväinen. I have reproduced the answer below.

> A group $G$ with the property is called sequenceable. For a survey, see [this paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/viewFile/DS10/pdf) by M. A. Ollis, which also tells that sequenceable groups are related to constructing row-complete latin squares. It is conjectured by Keedwell that $D_6,D_8$ and $Q_8$ are the only non-abelian non-sequenceable groups (see page 17); in particular, there should be none with odd order. It is known that an abelian group is sequenceable if and only if it has a unique element of order 2 (see page 5 for a proof). The article gives a list of groups that are known to be sequenceable. Apparently the question is not completely solved even in the case where $|G|$ has two prime factors.
>
> However, some groups of odd order are known to be sequenceable, so an example to your question would be for instance the non-abelian group of order 21 (page 5; there are other examples as well).